# Creating a redistributable GCC package able to build dynamic libraries

Tags: gcc, build, redistributable

Case in point, a have a program that needs to be able to load dynamic libraries from runtime created arbitrary source files. The program is licensed under GPL. The program should ship as a package free of any external dependencies, ie. run out of an unzipped package.

Ideally, it should work as a portable, platform independent IDE (different binaries for different targets of course). Targets in mind are OSX 10.8++ and Windows, both in 32 and 64 bit formats. I need it to support C and C++ only.

I envision it as GCC placed in a subdirectory and invoked from a platform-supported script (like .bat files and bash etc.) with the goal of producing a dynamic library that can be loaded right away (ie. a DLL or a dylib) - through a classic commandline. The script will be fed with input / output files and include directories.

Can i use GCC for this - and how can i obtain/create such a package? Would this be legal from a license context? How about the standard library source files?

Any help with this project is hugely welcomed.

Comment: Note that your 'GCC' will need support in the form of the assembler and linker, which can be from `binutils`.  When you build GCC, you specify the directory where it is expected to be installed.  On Unix-like systems, you can use a symlink from where it is expected to where it is actually installed. Technically, beyond the size of the code (around 360 MiB for GCC 4.8.2 without `binutils` on Mac OS X 10.9.1), there's nothing to stop you doing this.  IANAL, but since you're just using GCC, you should be OK on that score too.

Comment: So a working minimal package is ~400 mb at least?

Comment: Dunno about minimal; that's the basic install but it includes Objective C and Java (and Fortran).  If you omitted those, it would decrease, but you are probably looking at hundreds of megabytes of code to support the compilation — yes.